# Loading Components in cake php according to certain conditions

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

In app_controller.php

```
 var $components = array('Session', 'Component1', 'Component2');
```

I want to avoid loading of all components when `$this->params['prefix'] == admin`, only

```
var $components = array('Session');
```

is enough there..

How to do it  ?

Is it possible to not load a component for a particular controller method

```
class PagesController extends AppController
{

    function search()
    {
    // avoid loading  of components ('Component1' and  'Component2') here which is loaded in app_controller  '$components' array
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can override the constructor then (if the information is already available this soon):

```
public function __construct(CakeRequest $request = null, CakeResponse $response = null) {
    if ($this->params['prefix'] == 'admin') {
        $this->components[] = 'Session';
    }
    parent::__construct($request, $response);
}
```

But IMO its kinda silly to include the session component only for admin (since the overhead to program this is way beyond what you gain by doing it)

PS: there is also the manual (and probably cleaner) way:

```
public function beforeFilter(){
    parent::beforeFilter();
    if ($this->params['prefix'] == 'admin') {
        $this->Session = $this->Components->load('Session');
    }
}
```